# Green Corrosion on new sink shut off valve after only a year

Tags: plumbing, valve, shutoff

[image]

I just noticed some green corrosion around the shut off valve area under a bathroom sink. This is a new shut off valve that was installed by a plumbing company only around a year ago. Should I have them come out to re do it?

Comment: is there any indication of a leak at the joint?  This level of copper oxidation is often the result of a wet joint or low spot accumulating water drips.

Comment: There is a dried green dot right under this area.  My thought is there was maybe a very small drip that caused this build up and now the corrosion has sealed things off perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

It may simply be condensation on a cold water line.  The rule of thumb in plumbing is if the joint isn't leaking don't eff with it.

Comment: Think of it as a feature of copper alloys. Metal loss would be nearly impossible to measure ( It would require removal and laboratory testing).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps excess acid flux was not wiped off. Vigorously wipe the area with a wet paper towel and see if the green deposits come off. If they don't, then rub with a terry cloth rag wetted with hot water. Probably the green will not return.

Comment: Pretty clearly a threaded connection.

Comment: I saw signs of threads, but in my (limited) experience all shut-off valves are connected to the house supply  by sweated or compression so I decided not to believe my lying eyes.